# Lodash differenceBy clarification

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, lodash

I have two arrays of objects, I want to find the difference between newData and oldData arrays by `identifier`, show difference, where identifiers of oldData are different from newData array, here are my arrays:

```
const newData = [
    {
        "extras": {},
        "identifier": "13",
        "latitude": 39.13063,
        "loiteringDelay": 1000,
        "longitude": -86.58286,
        "notifyOnDwell": false,
        "notifyOnEntry": true,
        "notifyOnExit": true,
        "radius": 30,
    },
    {
        "extras": {},
        "identifier": "18",
        "latitude": 39.13063,
        "loiteringDelay": 1000,
        "longitude": -86.58286,
        "notifyOnDwell": false,
        "notifyOnEntry": true,
        "notifyOnExit": true,
        "radius": 30,
    }

]

const oldData = [
    {
        "identifier": "13",
        "latitude": 39.13063,
        "loiteringDelay": 1000,
        "longitude": -86.58286,
        "notifyOnDwell": false,
        "notifyOnEntry": true,
        "notifyOnExit": true,
        "radius": 30,
    },
    {
        "identifier": "12",
        "latitude": 39.13063,
        "loiteringDelay": 1000,
        "longitude": -86.58286,
        "notifyOnDwell": false,
        "notifyOnEntry": true,
        "notifyOnExit": true,
        "radius": 30,
    }
]
```

Here what I'm doing:

```
let testDifference = _.differenceBy(newData, oldData, "identifier")
```

My expectation, that I will get

```
[
    {
        "identifier": "12",
        "latitude": 39.13063,
        "loiteringDelay": 1000,
        "longitude": -86.58286,
        "notifyOnDwell": false,
        "notifyOnEntry": true,
        "notifyOnExit": true,
        "radius": 30,
    },
]
```

in reality, I'm getting empty array, what I'm doing wrong? How to make it work correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just need to switch around the first two parameters to `differenceBy` to get the result you're expecting. You can think of it as the first array items **except** the second array items.

```js
const newData = [{
  "extras": {},
  "identifier": "13",
  "latitude": 39.13063,
  "loiteringDelay": 1000,
  "longitude": -86.58286,
  "notifyOnDwell": false,
  "notifyOnEntry": true,
  "notifyOnExit": true,
  "radius": 30,
}]

const oldData = [{
    "identifier": "13",
    "latitude": 39.13063,
    "loiteringDelay": 1000,
    "longitude": -86.58286,
    "notifyOnDwell": false,
    "notifyOnEntry": true,
    "notifyOnExit": true,
    "radius": 30,
  },
  {
    "identifier": "12",
    "latitude": 39.13063,
    "loiteringDelay": 1000,
    "longitude": -86.58286,
    "notifyOnDwell": false,
    "notifyOnEntry": true,
    "notifyOnExit": true,
    "radius": 30,
  }
];

let whatDelete = _.differenceBy(oldData, newData, "identifier");

console.log(whatDelete);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Weird, I tried that first and it didn't work. I must have mistyped something.